# Google Chrome Extensions Interacting With Secure Website

Tags: security, google-chrome-extension

There is a third-party google chrome extension that has been written to interact with my website.   It automatically logs a client computer into my website and then submits information to a particular page on my website.

Once this client computer is logged into my secure website, is there a way for this Chrome extension to extract information from other pages that would only be visible when a user is logged into my website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, chrome extensions have full access to everything you are doing in the browser while the extension is enabled.

Comment: Thank you.   So if I have this chrome extension installed and I log into my bank account, it could essentially download all my bank transactions and store them in a database?

Comment: Yes that is possible.

Comment: Thank you again!   If I have users using my website with this Chrome Extension installed, is there a way in my websites server logs to determine if the extension is extracting information from my secure website?